# Как скачать отправленный мне файл?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

только учусь использовать библиотеку pyrogram, в документации не совсем поняла: предположим мне отправили некий файл **hello.exe** , каким образом я могу скачать его в туже папку где лежит мой python скрипт? Мне бы помог простой пример с объяснением.

Answer (score 0):

В pyrogram существует прекрасный метод - `Client.download_media()`
Простейший пример:

```
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client("my_account")


@app.on_message()
async def my_handler(client, message):
    await app.download_media(message) #скачиваем в папку к боту 


app.run()
```

Дальше можно фильтровать, чтобы, например, принимать только документы/фото/видео и т.д.